# Mapping between each bit in a bitmap index and tuple-pointers

Tags: postgresql, bitmap-index

Bitmap Indexes are described [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12553.1135634231@sss.pgh.pa.us), but I don't understand some part of it.

> A plain indexscan fetches one tuple-pointer at a time from the index,
>   and immediately visits that tuple in the table.  A bitmap scan fetches
>   all the tuple-pointers from the index in one go, sorts them using an
>   in-memory "bitmap" data structure, and then visits the table tuples in
>   physical tuple-location order.  The bitmap scan improves locality of
>   reference to the table at the cost of more bookkeeping overhead to
>   manage the "bitmap" data structure --- and at the cost that the data
>   is no longer retrieved in index order, which doesn't matter for your
>   query but would matter if you said ORDER BY.

To visit the table tuples, you need to know the tuple-pointers. Then there must be a mapping between each bit in a bitmap and tuple-pointers. How is this mapping maintained?

I also don't understand what he meant by "sorts them **using** an in-memory "bitmap" data structure".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no `bitmap` index type. The `Bitmap Index Scan` is just a fast mechanism to look up and sort values from a bitmap.

The Backend Process scans the Index for all tuples, and stores them in a structure called `TIDBitmap`. The pointers to the tuples are sorted so they could be accessed sequential on disk.

The source of the Bitmap structure could be found in [src/backend/nodes/tidbitmap.c](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/nodes/tidbitmap.c;h=dfeb7d5c630794f9d0e26f01fd2ba284f344c4b3;hb=HEAD)